# How can I use Live Reload 2 on a local wordpress website on MAMP?

Tags: php, wordpress, livereload

I'm looking to do a live refresh on file save just like I would with my static sites locally. I'm using the latest version of wordpress on a fresh install. I have no problem using Live Reload to compile my scss files. I've tried to add my

```
<script>document.write('<script src="http://' + (location.host || 'localhost').split(':')[0] + ':PORT_HERE/livereload.js?snipver=1"></' + 'script>')</script>
```

below the body as instructed and I've also tried to put this in the head. In either the footer.php or header.php file. Neither has worked, how is Live Reload 2 used with MAMP/Wordpress locally?

Using Live Reload 2.3.26

Comment: In the LiveReload bottom status bar how many browsers are connected? Try updating to LiveReload 2.3.27, use [this WordPress plugin](https://gist.github.com/peterwilsoncc/2155237), and install the LiveReload plugin in Chrome/Safari.

Comment: Ok thanks, the plugin worked great iloveitaly.